# Access option values webdriver.io

Tags: javascript, testing, webdriver-io

Right now with my ui tests using WebdriverIO, I have this in my configuration file:

```
var baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000';

global.testParameters = {
  baseUrl: baseUrl
};
```

This gives me access to my base url in the tests however it has to be fixed in the configuration file and I can't use the --baseUrl option when running wdio command.  The reason for this is because from everything I have read, I don't see a way to have access to command line option values in my tests.

Is there a way to access the value of the command line options (specifically --baseUrl) in my actual test files?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs) library. Do `npm install yargs` and in your config file add:

```
var argv = require('yargs').argv;
var baseUrl = argv.baseUrl;
```

You can then pass in the baseUrl with `--baseUrl <your URL>`

You can also make use of the WebdriverIO spec ([wdio.conf.js](http://webdriver.io/guide/testrunner/configurationfile.html)) for configuration and create a separate conf.js file for each baseUrl you'd like to run your tests against

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your base location through command line using `-baseUrl=` like below

```
wdio --baseUrl=http://[device IP]
```

You can pass any argument you need using the same way and can access it in wdio.config.js '`onprepare`' event like below

```
wdio --type=XXX
```

Then in wdio config

```
onPrepare: function(config, capabilities) {
    if (process.argv !== undefined && process.argv.length) {
        process.argv.forEach(arg => {
                if (arg.indexOf('--type=') !== -1) {
                    process.env.type = arg.replace('--type=', '');
                }
        });
    }
},
before: function(capabilities, specs) {
      global.type = process.env.type;
}
```

Now your type is available through-out your workspace as a global variable.